# How do Multi-Level Page Tables Actually Save Space

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, page-tables

I've been trying to do some research on why multi level page tables save space, and I think I'm a little confused on how a page table itself works. I found the following from [Cornell](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4410/2015su/lectures/lec14-pagetables.html):

> The page table needs one entry per page. Assuming a 4GB (2^32 byte) virtual and physical address space   and a page size of 4kB (2^12 bytes), we see that the the 2^32 byte address space must be split into 2^20 pages.

It is my understanding each process has its own page table. Does this mean that each process has 4GB of virtual address space? What is the point of the virtual address space being so huge? Why not allocate virtual pages as needed? Is it because the OS wants every possible address that can be made in the word size to map to a virtual page? Why not just prevent the program from dereferencing any virtual page number that is not a valid index for the page table?

I have read that one of the advantages of the multi-level page table is that it saves space by not having page table entries for virtual pages that are not in use. See below from Carnegie Mellon:

[image]

But why not just have a single level page table that has continuous entries - why would the process need PTE 1, 2, and then skip to 8? Why allow that? Even still, why do all the trailing, unused PTE's exist? Why not cut the page table short?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I've already read it. I guess the crux of what confuses me is why each process needs such a massive page table. Why can't they have the illusion of a massive virtual address space, and the page table can just contain the mappings for the virtual pages the process is currently using?

Comment: I guess you're also lost at the difference between the "Gap" and "1023 unallocated pages," in the slide, then?

Comment: By "saving space" it does not mean "minimizing the virtual address space." It means saving the space occupied by the page table itself so that it doesn't need to allocate the whole continuous array of PTEs, which comes at the cost of even more space occupied by non-leaf nodes when every single page from 0 to 4GB gets allocated. If it could not skip the 2-7 for the Gap, it would have to allocate 1024 PTEs for each, resulting in +(6*1024*8) bytes increase in memory usage.

Comment: Also note that the virtual address is split into multiple slice of bits and each of them is used as an integer indices into the page table "array".

Comment: Thank you for reply. I understand that, what confuses me is why the page table needs to be so big? Why is the virtual address space so big, why does the gap exist?

Comment: The point of virtual address space is to enable *paging* i.e. create a transparent "illusion" that even more memory is available than what physically exists. This enables on-demand file mappings where the OS kernel loads file into memory when requested and discard and/or flush it to disk when the system needs memory for more important tasks. That and sparse arrays of which most part is never written / always 0 but we can rely on MMU and allocate a large virtual memory space rather than software-driven dense encoding and et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a system with a 32-bit logical address space. If the
page size in such a system is 4 KB (2^12), then a page table may consist of over
1 million entries (2^20 = 2^32/2^12). Assuming that each entry consists of 4 bytes,
each process may need up to 4 MB of physical address space for the page table
alone.

Clearly, we would not want to allocate the page table contiguously in
main memory. One simple solution to this problem is to divide the page table
into smaller pieces. We can accomplish this division in several ways.
One way is to use a two-level paging algorithm, in which the page table
itself is also paged. For example, consider again the system with
a 32-bit logical address space and a page size of 4 KB. A logical address is
divided into a page number consisting of 20 bits and a page offset consisting
of 12 bits. Because we page the page table, the page number is further divided
into a 10-bit page number and a 10-bit page offset.
[Two-level paging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvhO7.png)

--Silberschatz A., Galvin P.B.

So for the case proposed above we would use 2^10 * 4B = 4KB for the outer page (p1) and only N * 2^10 * 4B= N * 4KB of inner page tables where N is the number of the needed pages for a process, which in total is less than the space needed for a non-leveled page table (4MB).

You should also notice that the process only occupies the number of pages and memory needed, and the maximum virtual address space determines the maximum addressable and thus occupiable memory for a process given a system configuration (32/64 bit address space).

Answer (score 0):

This saves memory (the word "space" is not specific enough) because the level 1 page table is much smaller when using two-level page tables instead of one. We can just keep level 1 page table in memory and paged out some level 2 page tables to disk.

[image: Multi-level page tables]

You can watch [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Z4kSOv49GNc) to learn about size of page table and multi-level page tables.